# Android Facebook wall post - publish_action permission not authorized

Tags: android, facebook, publish

I am currently developing an application where I just need to post the message on Facebook user's timeline saying that " I am currently using X application and you can download it from ".

Now for this I need the Facebook permission which is "publish_actions".

When I try to open an authorize dialog with this permission, I am having the following error, so now user is not even asked for the publish_actions permission, and so I am not being able to post any message on the user's wall.

[image]

I am right now using the application id of the test app that I have created of my real application registered on Facebook. Also when I try the Application id of real application, I am getting the same error.

Can anyone tell me why this error is coming? Do I need to submit my application first to Facebook or what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#review

If you request publish_actions, you need to submit your app for review.

Comment: Ok, I thought so, but wasn't quite sure about this, as it was working well to publish post on wall earlier even without submitting the app. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @PriyankJoshi you're right, you don't need to submit app with `publish_actions` permission if you call `requestNewPublishPermissions`.